# Confused by local scope and function Parameters

Tags: c++

Hello im confused by function parameters.
I've had a guy try and help me but i struggle to understand. I've been following learncpp

And local scope confuses me when it comes to parameters.

It says on learncpp, That if you declare a function

`int foo(int x, int y) // int x and y are local`

So How then can i access those parameters if it is local using a function.

Here is my code with what im struggling with.

```
double increaseSpeedControl(int Speed, int max) // int speed and int max are local
{ // local scope

    if (Speed <= 100)
    {
        int max{ 100 };
        while (Speed < max)
        {
            std::cout << "Increasing : " << Speed++ << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return Speed;
} // end of scope 

int main()
{ // local scope
    std::cout << "Set Current Speed :";
    int sp{};
    std::cin >> sp;
    std::cout << "Speed Increased :" << increaseSpeedControl(sp, 100) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Now : " << sp; 

 // How then am i able to access increaseSpeedControl(sp, 100) 
if inside the function is a local scope?


} // end local scope
```

This is really hard for me to grasp and i would appreciate some help.

Comment: "*How then am i able to access increaseSpeedControl(sp, 100)*" Is this your question? It's hard to tell what you're asking here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well it states on learncpp, Chapter 2.5 that parameters inside of a function are local scope. So we cannot access them outside of scope, How am i able to access them using a function(params) inside of main.

Comment: You're accessing the *function* in `main` (you declared the function in the global scope). But the parameters, `Speed` and `max` in your code, will not be accessible in `main`.

Comment: So how am i able to get a return if i input parameters is my question. Like if i can make my own local variables in main and recall that function. How does it give me output if everything inside of the function is local scope it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: From `main`'s perspective, the function is a black box. The box has two holes labeled `Speed` and `max`. `main` inserts two `int`'s and lets the box do its thing. Then the box spits out an `int` at the end for `main`. At no point can `main` see into that box to access `Speed` or `max` (those are local only to the box). `main` can only feed two values in and wait for one to be spat back out. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Absolutely thank you so much i really appreciate that thank you. It was confusing me for so damn long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `main`'s perspective, the function is a black box. The box has two holes labeled `Speed` and `max`. `main` inserts two `int`'s and lets the box do its thing. Then the box spits out an `int` at the end for `main`. At no point can `main` see into that box to access `Speed` or `max` (those are local only to the box). `main` can only feed two values in and wait for one to be spat back out.

This is what we mean when we say that variables are "local." They exist only in the black box where no one outside of the scope can see them.